# How to use Selenium.click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So i was working on getting some file from https://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player. Im using selenium with chrome webdriver. I cant quite figure out how to click on the "get stats". I can do this manually but would like to do it through the html and selenium.

Have tried this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player')
element = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
element.click()
```

But nothing happens. Im not sure how understand the output from find_elements_by_tag_name. Gets something like "this selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="14bacd9bab4b484952ba872ea0373663", element="4ef4e9da-b193-46a8-8209-265b8bef3f05"" (it differs in after the equal signs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that out, should help:

```
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player')
time.sleep(4)
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Get Stats']")
element.click()
```

or you can use explicitly wait, like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


timeout = 30
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player')
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Get Stats']")))
myElem.click()
```

Comment: Ahh okay worked with element*. Just a question. Tried something like that based on previous answer. How do u know it is "text()=get stats" - in the html it does not say text?

Comment: hmm okay just examples i saw where it was explicit what it was like id=somthing. The data-v-... is that of any importance?

Comment: Not sure to confirm where :/

Comment: the last part with timeout does not seem to work tho.

Comment: @Younglolk it works 100%, just double check it, what error did you have?

Comment: @Younglolk it's up to you what wait way using, I suggested both, last one is more flexible and right, but complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is a bit over kill here since the data is returned form the api. Just grab the data from there. You'll also get all the data and not have to go through each dropdown  for Scoring, Assists, Rebounds, etc. (all 248 columns)

If you want the per game and/or per 100 possession, then it's just a matter of dividing the numerical int columns by the `'GP'` or `'Possessions' * 100` columns once you have the dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-totals/nba'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'Season': '2020-21',
'SeasonType': 'Regular+Season',
'Type': 'Player'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['multi_row_table_data'])

df.to_csv('pbpstats_export.csv', index=False)
```

The data will come with the column in alpha order, so if you want to move them before writing to file, you can put which columns you want to come first. I just choose the name and team since those typically are the first 2 columns in a sports table:

```
# If you want to reorder the first few columns. Otherwise columns are i alpha order
reorder = ['Name','TeamAbbreviation']
for col in reversed(reorder):
    col = df.pop(col)
    df.insert(0, col.name, col)
```

**Ouput:**

```
print(df)
                  Name TeamAbbreviation  2pt And 1 Free Throw Trips  \
0        Julius Randle              NYK                        35.0   
1         Nikola Jokic              DEN                        24.0   
2          Buddy Hield              SAC                         3.0   
3     Domantas Sabonis              IND                        32.0   
4           RJ Barrett              NYK                        21.0   
..                 ...              ...                         ...   
495      Jontay Porter              MEM                         NaN   
496  Ty-Shon Alexander              PHX                         NaN   
497      Rayjon Tucker              PHI                         NaN   
498     Brian Bowen II              IND                         1.0   
499       Jared Harper              NYK                         NaN   

     Arc3Accuracy  Arc3Assists  ...  BlockedCorner3  Period3Fouls5Minutes  \
0        0.408284         90.0  ...             NaN                   NaN   
1        0.422360         87.0  ...             NaN                   NaN   
2        0.365796         22.0  ...             NaN                   NaN   
3        0.281818        101.0  ...             NaN                   NaN   
4        0.318681         32.0  ...             NaN                   NaN   
..            ...          ...  ...             ...                   ...   
495      0.500000          NaN  ...             NaN                   NaN   
496           NaN          NaN  ...             NaN                   NaN   
497      1.000000          NaN  ...             NaN                   NaN   
498           NaN          NaN  ...             NaN                   NaN   
499           NaN          NaN  ...             NaN                   NaN   

     HeaveMakes  Period1Fouls3Minutes  Period2Fouls4Minutes  
0           NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
1           NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
2           NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
3           NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
4           NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
..          ...                   ...                   ...  
495         NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
496         NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
497         NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
498         NaN                   NaN                   NaN  
499         NaN                   NaN                   NaN  

[500 rows x 248 columns]
```

Comment: Oh i dont quite know what api is. My plan was to get the stats and click export stats in the bottom of the page and then do it for them all. I dont know if that is very impratical compared to using api.

Comment: Well, both ways will get the job done. Sort of depends on what you're trying to do. sort of like if you wanted to drive in a nail. Both a sledge hammer and regular hammer will do it, but one may be a better choice given the options. In this case, the API is more efficient way to do it and will be more robust (it's not reliant on the html structure). I also added the part to write to file, which is essentially what the export to csv is.

Comment: Can see i work more effektive but how do u know how write it up in python?

Comment: What do you mean? Not sure what you’re asking here.

Comment: If you mean how I knew about the api. If you go to Dev Tools on the browser, and go to Network -> XHR, you can see the request made. Just a matter of pulling out the url from there and looking at the Preview tab to see what’s returned.

Answer (score 1):

you can perform a click like that :

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player')
time.sleep(5)
element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//* 
 [@id="totals"]/main/div[3]/div/button[1]')[0]
element.click()
```

Comment: That won't work as you're using `find_elements_by_tag_name` (note the s in elements) which returns a list.

Comment: Ahh my bad. I have tried element.click but there doesnt happend anything. The webdriver do not update.

Comment: Thanks for it - it helped.

Comment: if it worked then u should accept it as an answer .